Unable to click 'Accept All' on the "Before You Continue To Google" pop-up. Selenium WebDriver C#
I am trying to write a simple Google Search test using Selenium WebDriver C# However, when I hit the "Before you continue to Google" pop-up my tests are unable to click on the 'Accept All' button.
So far I have tried accessing the element via ID and XPath with no success:
driver.FindElement(By.Id("L2AGLb")).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='L2AGLb']")).Click();

....
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
 
namespace OMSDemo
{
    public class TestCase1
    {
        IWebDriver driver;
        WebDriverWait wait;
 
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(TestData.GoogleURL);
 
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
 
 
        }
 
        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("L2AGLb")));
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
 
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("L2AGLb")).Click();
 
            /* IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("iframe"));
             foreach (IWebElement element in elements)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(element.Text);
             } */
 
        }
    }
}


"With no success"... you never describe what happens. Do you get an error or ? If you get an error, add the full error message as text to your question, properly formatted. If no error, describe what happens or doesn't happen that you are expecting.

You're not setting the driver class member correctly, but rather, creating a new local variable with the same name.
